# Center align for nav isn't aligned with header (also centered)

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-align

Both my nav and my header are set to be aligned center, however the nav is pushed farther right than everything else on the page. I've tried changing the padding and margin to 0 but it doesn't help. It also is happening with the links in my footer so I'm thinking it might have something to do with the fact that they are links.

```css
/*NAVIGATION*/
nav {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e4e6e5;
  width: 100%;
   border-bottom: solid #05182e 2px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto
}

nav a{
 border-radius: 10%;
 padding: 8px;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 color: #1f3b5a;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 30px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav a:hover{
 font-size: 40px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav img{
 width: 30%;
 border: none;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav img:hover{
 width: 40%;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav ul {
   margin: 0;
}
nav ul li:last-child a {
  background-color:#e4e6e5; 
} 

/*HEADER*/
section.header{
 margin-top:40px;
 color: #05182e;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
 padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
 <nav> 
     <ul> 
      <li><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Canadian Women's Hockey League Logo"></li>
         <li> <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
         <li> <a href="roster.html" target="_blank">Roster</a></li>
         <li> <a href="schedule.html" target="_blank">Schedule</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://cwhl.ca" target="_blank"><img src="images/cwhllogo.png"></a></li>

     </ul>
 </nav>

<!-- HEADER -->
 <section class="header">
     <h1>
      Brampton Thunder
     </h1> 
 </section>
```

Comment: The image logo is pushing it to the right I've just removed the image and now it's centred

Answer (score 0):

Add the following so it does not interfere with your menu it should remain centered With the below

```
 nav img{
    width: 30%;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }
```